# Which REST API can be used for product comparison in Magento 2?

Tags: node.js, rest, magento2

I want to implement an API for comparing products in Magento 2 through nodeJs. I am having difficulty finding the particular API in swagger also can someone help me with the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would do a simple search through catalog with 2 to N sku in parameter, i.e :

```
http://magento2.url/rest/V1/products/?
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=sku&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=PRD01&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][field]=sku&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][value]=PRD02&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][condition_type]=eq
```

as it returns the essential data